# Nuances between "люди бывают разными", "люди могут быть разными", and "люди могут оказаться разными"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> 1) Думаю, люди **бывают** совершенно **разными**.

```
=??? People can be totally different (vary from person to person) sometimes.
```

> {vs}: 2) Думаю, люди **могут быть** совершенно **разными**.
>
> {vs}: 3) Думаю, люди могут **оказаться** совершенно **разными** (по своим ...).

I assume  the 1st sentence with "бывать" means something along the lines of "to each his own", but how does it compare with the 2nd and the 3rd?

As an aside: Do "бывать" and "оказаться" always take the instrumental case, just as "быть" does?

Comment: #1 is totally generic, #2 implies some pre-selection of people, #3 focuses on contrast between positive pre-selection and divergent outcome.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Люди бывают совершенно разными. People are totally different.
> 2. Люди могут быть совершенно разными. People can be totally different.
> 3. Люди могуг оказаться совершенно разными. People may turn out to be totally different.

The first is a neutral opinion. The second is a supposition. The third shows how unexpected things can be.
Yes, the instrumental case is required.

Answer (score 1):

Люди бывают совершенно разны**е**:

> There are totally different kinds of people.

Люди бывают совершенно разны**ми**:

> People can behave totally differrent [in different situations].

Люди могут быть совершенно разными:

> People [suitable for that job] can be totally differrent.

Люди могут оказаться совершенно разными:

> People may turn out to be incompatible (with each other. [e.g. in a marriage])
>
> or (unexpectedly) not suitable for some task.